# C SHA1() open file and get hash error when compiling

Tags: c, sha1

I'm writing a program to get a hash for some files and do stuff with them. I'm trying to extract hash and such, but when I'm compiling I'm getting an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    // para digitar em vez de   //char str[50] = {0};   //scanf("Enter file name:%s", str);     //scanf     if ( argc < 1 ) /* argc should be at least 2 for correct execution */
     {
        printf( "falta o ficheiro para ter hash: %s filename", argv[0] );
        }
        else
        {
        // filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );     //char str[] = "teste";     //const char str[] = "Original String";     unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // == 20

    SHA1(FILE, sizeof(FILE), hash);

    printf("SHA1 of %s is %s\n", argv[1], hash);

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }

    }
    return 0; }
```

getting this error when compiling with: gcc sob.c -o sha -lcrypto

```
sob.c: In function ‘main’:
sob.c:24:7: error: expected expression before ‘FILE’
  SHA1(FILE, sizeof(FILE), hash);
       ^
sob.c:24:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘SHA1’
In file included from sob.c:2:0:
/usr/include/openssl/sha.h:126:16: note: declared here
 unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md);
                ^
```

Comment: The error message tells you that you're calling the function with the incorrect (number of) parameters.  You are expected to pass a character buffer as the first argument; you're trying to pass a type name.  Even if you changed `FILE` to `file`, it would not work correctly: you can't pass a file stream to the function — you must read the data from the file and pass the data to the function.  I'm not sure of the purpose of the third parameter; you need to read the function's [manual page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/sha.html).

Comment: ty, tought i could send it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass in a file (or `FILE`, which is a type, not a variable) to SHA1, instead you need to read the file into an unsigned char array and pass in that array!